# conditionally add an xmlattribute to an xmlelement with Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm dealing with a system that accepts data loads in XML format. For example, there's a field called "col1", and that field has the value "world" in it. The system interprets `<col1 />`, `<col1></col1>`, and a missing `<col1>` element as "no change" to the field called `col1`. (This is good because, if we were creating new data, "no change" would mean to accept whatever the default value is.) If I need to delete whatever is in the field, the `<col1>` element needs to have an `xsi:nil` attribute with a value of `true`.

So, when I'm extracting data from one instance of the system to load into another instance (inserting with SQL is not an option), I need to conditionally add `xsi:nil="true"` attribute to the XML returned from a query in Oracle 12c to explicitly indicate that the value of the element is null. (Always adding `xsi:nil` with a value of `true` or `false`, as appropriate, could work but is not desirable as it breaks convention and bloats file size.)

A test case can be set up as follows.

```
create table table1 (id number(10), col1 varchar2(5));
insert into table1 values (1,'hello');
insert into table1 values (2,null);
commit;
```

I want to to get this back from a query:

```
<outer><ID>1</ID><COL1>hello</COL1></outer>
<outer><ID>2</ID><COL1 xsi:nil="true"></COL1></outer>
```

This query throws an error.

```
select
    xmlelement("outer",
        xmlforest(id),
        (case col1
            when null then xmlelement(COL1, xmlattributes('xsi:nil="true"'), null)
            else xmlforest(col1)
            end)
    )
from table1
;
```

Is there some other way to conditionally include the `xmlattributes` call, or some other way to get the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NVL2` to make it slightly less verbose:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  XMLELEMENT(
          "outer",
          XMLFOREST( id ),
          XMLELEMENT( col1, xmlattributes( NVL2(col1,NULL,'true') as "xsi:nil"), col1 )
        ).getClobVal() AS element
FROM    table1;
```

**Result**:

```
OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------
<outer><ID>1</ID><COL1>hello</COL1></outer>
<outer><ID>2</ID><COL1 xsi:nil="true"></COL1></outer>
```

**Query 2**: You could also use `XMLFOREST` to generate the elements and then `APPENDCHILDXML` to append the missing element (including namespaces are left as an exercise to the OP):

```
SELECT  APPENDCHILDXML( 
          XMLELEMENT( "outer", XMLFOREST( id, col1 ) ),
          '/outer',
          NVL2( col1, NULL, XMLTYPE('<COL1 nil="true"></COL1>') )
        ).getClobVal() AS element
FROM    table1;
```

**Result**:

```
OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------
<outer><ID>1</ID><COL1>hello</COL1></outer>
<outer><ID>2</ID><COL1 nil="true"/></outer>
```

Comment: I like Query 1 / the NVL2() suggestion better than my CASE, so I'll give you the Answer credit for it. I find Query 2 convoluted (so the next guy will have more difficulty maintaining it), and I don't like hard-coding the whole tag (I could have skipped all the xml functions and just done strings if I wanted to do that).

Comment: Hi , If i want to display the <outer> element conditionally , how would you do it?
For example., i want to validate against a variable and if the variable is yes , then print the <outer> with a value if no then do not print even an empty tag. i am thinking in same lines as using a case inside xmlforest but it seems to get messy.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this query works, but it's more verbose than I would like.

```
select
    xmlelement("outer",
        xmlforest(id),
        xmlelement(col1,xmlattributes(case when col1 is null then 'true' else null end as "xsi:nil"), col1)
        ).getClobVal()
from table1
;
```

Comment: It can be a bit more compact without `else null`, not necessary in the `case`

Comment: That helps, but I think I'm really wishing I could use xmlforest() and optionally supply the xmlattributes(). Sending col1 to xmlelement() twice is annoying, but xmlforest doesn't take xmlattributes().